# Геттер возвращает одно и то же свойсво объекта

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Геттер в вычисляемых свойстах во Vue.js 2, возвращает одно и то же свойство объекта. Хотя по идеи должны возвращаться следующие свойства(цвета)

```js
export let colors = {
    data () {
        return {
            palette: {
                blue: '#0772A1',
                green: '#00B74A',
                orange: '#FF8700',
            }
        }
    },
    computed: {
        color: {
            get () {
                for (let item in this.palette) {
                    let color = this.palette[item]
                    delete this.palette[item]
                    return color
                }
            }
        }
    },
}
```

Comment: Не понятна ваша задача. Зачем вы вообще используете `computed` как итератор еще и удаляя свойства из объекта после каждой итерации? Нужны уточнения по поводу того, какого эффекта вы хотите достичь. Почему бы просто не воспользоватся `v-for`

Comment: Ну вот например, нам нужны цвета в другом компоненте для построения графика, с помощью геттера, мы получаем цвет из обьекта (this.color - вернет цвет) думаю так удобнее, чем Object.values(this.palette)[i]. Но vue.js в computed возращает один и тот же цвет, м б я чего-то не понимаю.

Comment: Если нужно вернуть цвет по индексу, лучше сделать это через `action`. `computed` не совсем для этого нужны. В 90% случаев вам вообще не нужно будет модифицировать геттеры\сеттеры. Да и не понятно зачем вам использовать `Object.values`, когда можно обратиться к нужному цвету просто через свойство `this.colors.palette.blue`. Возможно проблема в том, каким именно образом вы передаете свою палитру в другой компонент.

Comment: ну через v-for и доступ к свойсту по ключу не подходят в моем случае. А вот про action не знаю, еще не изучал vuex

Comment: Извиняюсь, перепутал, `vuex` здесь не нужен. Я про `methods`